# RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Tags: android

I am getting a run time exception

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id
>   attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

I don't know what is wrong.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newslist);
    mDbHelper.open();
    fillData();
}

private void fillData() {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    long catID = extras.getLong("cat_id");
    Cursor c = mDbHelper.fetchNews(catID);
    startManagingCursor(c);

    String[] from = new String[] { DBHelper.KEY_TITLE };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.newslist_text };

    SimpleCursorAdapter notes = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.text_newslist, c, from, to);
    setListAdapter(notes);
}
```

**newslist.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ListView 
         android:id="@+id/catnewslist"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**text_newslist.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView 
        android:text="@+id/newslist_text"
        android:id="@+id/newslist_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">    
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: be sure to select an answer!

Comment: what is mDbHelper? i am on the same boat and trying to make it work my ListView...

Answer (score 189):

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

This will solve the error if you still want to use a ListActivity.

Comment: I had to use a different format, try `android:id="@+id/android:list"`  if it doesn't work. Your class must still extend ListActivity, and instead of doing `ListView yourListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.yourListView);` do this to initialize `ListView yourListView = getListView();`

Comment: @CQM here is any kind of pattern on this behavior?

Comment: This is the solution, if the OP ever cared to select an answer!

Comment: Why does this work? Why can't I assign any other value to android:id?

Comment: @VivekPandey, because you are extending the ListActivity which requires a ListView with an android:id of list, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html, zgcharley below explained it clearly

Comment: This is one of those sources of bugs where you think to yourself "who thought that this was obvious and why?".

Answer (score 53):

Remove the call to `setContentView` - you don't need it in a ListActivity unless you're doing something radical. The code should work without it.

Comment: But how does Activity know what template to apply if we don't use setContentView() ?

Comment: @ses, I believe it will use a pre-defined ListView template.

Answer (score 27):

Another way is, don't extend `ListActivity`. Just extends `Activity`, then you can create your list view by `setContentView()` and get the list view by `findViewById(R.id.yourlistview)`.

If you extends from `ListActivity`, then don't use `setContentView()`. You need get the default list view hosted in list activity by `getListView()`.

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar issue with the error message you received, and I found it was because I was extending ListActivity instead of just Activity (that's what I get for re-purposing code from a different project ;) )

Answer (score 6):

```
<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

I face like this too. In my case (Maybe not relevant with your case, just share to others) in class `mainActivity.java` 
`yourClassName extends ListActivity(){...}` change to `yourClassName extends Activity(){...}`

Comment: i found this really useful. thanks Baras for sharing this.

Comment: next beer is on me.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue, I was extending my activity class from listactivity, but the id of my list view was not defualt I changed it back to list and now its working fine.
Asim soroya