# application has stopped

Tags: android

I have a problem with my code and I don't seem to find it. The error is:

> Application has stopped unexpectedly!

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_BT_ENABLE = 0x1;

    ListView listGeraete;
    TextView text;
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    static private ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> BtDevices = null;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        listGeraete = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        listGeraete.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        registerReceiver(ActionFoundReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
    }

    // Aktivierung von Bluetooth
    public void ClickBtOn(View view)
    {
        bluetoothAdapter.enable();
        Intent enablerBt = new Intent(bluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enablerBt, REQUEST_BT_ENABLE);
    }

    // Deaktivierung von Bluetooth
    public void ClickBtOff(View view) {
        bluetoothAdapter.disable();
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(ActionFoundReceiver);
    }

    public void ClickBtScan(View view) {
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBt = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBt, REQUEST_BT_ENABLE);
    }
    arrayAdapter.clear();


    bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
}


private final BroadcastReceiver ActionFoundReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            arrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};





protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position, long id) {

super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);


if(bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {                               

    bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

 }
```

logcat is:

```
07-26 15:33:48.105: D/Process(3919): killProcess, pid=3919
07-26 15:33:48.105: D/Process(3919): dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
07-26 15:33:48.105: D/Process(3919): java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:599)
07-26 15:33:48.105: D/Process(3919): android.os.Process.killProcess(Process.java:788)
07-26 15:33:48.105: D/Process(3919): com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:104)
07-26 15:33:48.115: D/Process(3919): java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
07-26 15:33:48.115: D/Process(3919): java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
07-26 15:33:48.115: D/Process(3919): dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-26 15:33:48.115: I/Process(3919): Sending signal. PID: 3919 SIG: 9
07-26 15:34:09.476: D/AndroidRuntime(4062): Shutting down VM
07-26 15:34:09.476: W/dalvikvm(4062): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ad6228)
07-26 15:34:09.486: E/AndroidRuntime(4062): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-26 15:34:09.486: E/AndroidRuntime(4062): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.upcin.kommunikationuberbt/com.upcin.kommunikationuberbt.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
07-26 15:34:09.486: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
07-26 15:34:09.486: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
07-26 15:34:09.486: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
07-26 15:34:09.486: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
07-26 15:34:09.486: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-26 15:34:09.486: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
07-26 15:34:09.486: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
07-26 15:34:09.486: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-26 15:34:09.486: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-26 15:34:09.486: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-26 15:34:09.486: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-26 15:34:09.486: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-26 15:34:09.486: E/AndroidRuntime(4062): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
07-26 15:34:09.486: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:250)
07-26 15:34:09.486: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:281)
07-26 15:34:09.486: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1885)
07-26 15:34:09.486: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at com.upcin.kommunikationuberbt.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
07-26 15:34:09.486: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4531)
07-26 15:34:09.486: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
07-26 15:34:09.486: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
07-26 15:34:09.486: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: post the error message..

Answer (score 3):

Your log says everything

```
Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

It means that you need to set your `ListView's` **id** with `android.R.id.list`
So you must have a `ListView` in your layout `XML` file, with the `id="@android:id/list"`

```
<ListView
   android:id="@android:id/list"
   ...
/>
```

because you are extending from `ListActivity`.

Also you can have look at

- [`runtime exception ListView whose id attribute is
  'android.R.id.list'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040374/runtime-exception-listview-whose-id-attribute-is-android-r-id-list)

Comment: <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    /> 
</LinearLayout>

Comment: yes your id is incorrect, you need to use `android:id="@android:id/list"`