# application show unfortunately CustumMenuActivity has stopped

Tags: android

```
08-22 15:28:41.848: E/Trace(678): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-22 15:28:42.387: D/AndroidRuntime(678): Shutting down VM
08-22 15:28:42.387: W/dalvikvm(678): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
08-22 15:28:42.407: E/AndroidRuntime(678): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 15:28:42.407: E/AndroidRuntime(678): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vikram.custummenuactivity/com.vikram.custummenuactivity.CustumMenuActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
08-22 15:28:42.407: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
08-22 15:28:42.407: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
08-22 15:28:42.407: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
08-22 15:28:42.407: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
08-22 15:28:42.407: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-22 15:28:42.407: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-22 15:28:42.407: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-22 15:28:42.407: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 15:28:42.407: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-22 15:28:42.407: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-22 15:28:42.407: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-22 15:28:42.407: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-22 15:28:42.407: E/AndroidRuntime(678): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
08-22 15:28:42.407: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
08-22 15:28:42.407: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:259)
08-22 15:28:42.407: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
08-22 15:28:42.407: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at com.vikram.custummenuactivity.CustumMenuActivity.onCreate(CustumMenuActivity.java:24)
08-22 15:28:42.407: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
08-22 15:28:42.407: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
08-22 15:28:42.407: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
08-22 15:28:42.407: E/AndroidRuntime(678):  ... 11 more
08-22 15:33:42.558: I/Process(678): Sending signal. PID: 678 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: Show your code. It's almost impossible to help if there's no context for these errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So problem shouldn't be tricky. Your problem is:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a
>   ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

It means that you `ListView` should have id attibute `android.R.id.list`

```
<ListView
   android:id="@android:id/list"
   ...
/>
```

Similar topic:

- [`runtime exception ListView whose id attribute is
  'android.R.id.list'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040374/runtime-exception-listview-whose-id-attribute-is-android-r-id-list)

Answer (score 0):

From your stack trace:
"Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list". Add this id to the appropriate element in your XML layout file, for example: