# Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is android.R.id.list

Tags: android, listview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [runtime exception ListView whose id attribute is ‘android.R.id.list’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040374/runtime-exception-listview-whose-id-attribute-is-android-r-id-list)

I am new to android I get the following runtime error.

```
"Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is android.R.id.list"
```

I was trying following tutorial

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/
"Custom ArrayAdapter example"

when I run their code it works fine and they use android 2.3.3 
I use 4.0

I changed their code according to my requriment and got above runtime error in logcat.
here is my code.

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.xxxx.xxx.adapter.ListArrayAdapter;

public class Page5SubActivity extends ListActivity {

    static final String[] MOBILE_OS = new String[] { "Android", "iOS",
            "WindowsMobile", "Blackberry", "test", "test2" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.page5sub);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int val = intent.getIntExtra("id", 0);

        switch (val) {

        case 2:
            setListAdapter(new ListArrayAdapter(this, MOBILE_OS));

            break;

        case 3:
            break;

        case 4:
            break;

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        // get selected items
        String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, selectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void onClickBtn(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.back_arrow:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(Page5SubActivity.this,
                    Page5Activity.class);
            // intent2.putExtra("id", 2);
            startActivity(intent2);

            break;
        }

    }

}
```

Here is the code of xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/page1background"
    android:gravity="center" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/padding_Xlarge"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding_large"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_large"
        android:text="@string/text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/textbody" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/text" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout1"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Description" >
        </ImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@+id/label" >
        </TextView>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view3"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="4.5" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/back_arrow"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/backbut"
            android:contentDescription="@string/Description"
            android:onClick="onClickBtn"
            android:src="@drawable/backarrowpress" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view4"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="4.5" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

in their example they dont use listview widget in xml file but mention in the log cat.
apartfrom that it says unable to start activity compnonetinfo.

where do I have done wrong?
plz help me to correct this.

Here is the original code of the xml file.
here is the source of original code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="50px"
        android:layout_height="50px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
        android:layout_marginRight="20px"
        android:layout_marginTop="5px"
        android:src="@drawable/windowsmobile_logo" >
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="30px" >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I notice they dont have use listview widget in their xml file but works this example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution in your error

```
"Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is android.R.id.list"
```

If your are using ListActivity then you must have ListView in your xml of layout and must be id of ListView is `android.R.id.list`

So must add listview in your layout like below code

```
<ListView 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:id="@+id/android:list" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040374/runtime-exception-listview-whose-id-attribute-is-android-r-id-list

Comment: WHEN  i set as you metion whole my page become a item of list view. then (I had set an image for background, even that one is shown as a list item). how correct this?

Comment: @menukadevinda u can setBackground on listview or parent layout

Comment: it had set in a parent layout, that is a relavtive layout, now whole page is repeating lika list.

Comment: How to change list items color?

Answer (score 2):

when you extend ListActivity then your xml layout file must have ListView whose id is `android.R.id.list`

so put listview in xml layout file and `android:id="@+id/android.R.id.list"`

Comment: here is the original source code of the tutorial

Comment: in the tutorial they dont use android:id="@+id/android.R.id.list" though they have extend listactivity

Answer (score 1):

set your Listview id like this

```
android:id="@id/android:list"
```

Answer (score 1):

in your layout xml file you must set id of you ListView to @android:id/list

Answer (score 1):

set adapter like this.

```
  Adapter = new Adapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
```

or check XML

```
<ListView 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:id="@+id/android:list" />
```