# Receiving RuntimeException from lack of ListView despite xml

Tags: java, android, xml, runtime

Hello I am in my Android Project and I'm getting the following error. I have checked nearly every similar question and I am trying to use some solutions in here

***[RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040374/runtimeexception-your-content-must-have-a-listview-whose-id-attribute-is-andro)***

but they seem like they are inapplicable.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app, PID: 1309
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app/com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:293)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
at com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
```

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

Apparently, I must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list' and I unsure where to implement that in this case.

Here is my MainActivity Java:

```
package com.spicycurryman.getdisciplined10.app;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener;

import com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc;
import com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc.OnSeekArcChangeListener;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    private SeekArc mSeekArc;
    private SeekBar mRotation;
    private SeekBar mStartAngle;
    private SeekBar mSweepAngle;
    private SeekBar mArcWidth;
    private SeekBar mProgressWidth;
    private CheckBox mRoundedEdges;
    private CheckBox mTouchInside;
    private CheckBox mClockwise;
    private TextView mSeekArcProgress;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mSeekArc = (SeekArc) findViewById(R.id.seekArc);
        mSeekArcProgress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seekArcProgress);
        mRotation = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.rotation);
        mStartAngle = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.startAngle);
        mSweepAngle  = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.sweepAngle);
        mArcWidth = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.arcWidth);
        mProgressWidth = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.progressWidth);
        mRoundedEdges = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.roundedEdges);
        mTouchInside = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.touchInside);
        mClockwise = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.clockwise);

        mRotation.setProgress(mSeekArc.getArcRotation());
        mStartAngle.setProgress(mSeekArc.getStartAngle());
        mSweepAngle.setProgress(mSeekArc.getSweepAngle());
        mArcWidth.setProgress(mSeekArc.getArcWidth());
        mProgressWidth.setProgress(mSeekArc.getProgressWidth());

        mSeekArc.setOnSeekArcChangeListener(new OnSeekArcChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekArc seekArc) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekArc seekArc) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekArc seekArc, int progress,
                                          boolean fromUser) {
                mSeekArcProgress.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
            }
        });

        mRotation.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar view, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                mSeekArc.setArcRotation(progress);
                mSeekArc.invalidate();
            }
        });

        mStartAngle.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar view, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                mSeekArc.setStartAngle(progress);
                mSeekArc.invalidate();
            }
        });

        mSweepAngle.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar view, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                mSeekArc.setSweepAngle(progress);
                mSeekArc.invalidate();
            }
        });

        mArcWidth.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar view, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                mSeekArc.setArcWidth(progress);
                mSeekArc.invalidate();
            }
        });

        mProgressWidth.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar view, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                mSeekArc.setProgressWidth(progress);
                mSeekArc.invalidate();
            }
        });

        mRoundedEdges.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                mSeekArc.setRoundedEdges(isChecked);
                mSeekArc.invalidate();
            }
        });

        mTouchInside.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                mSeekArc.setTouchInSide(isChecked);
            }
        });

        mClockwise.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                mSeekArc.setClockwise(isChecked);
                mSeekArc.invalidate();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Here is my activity_main.xml that corresponds to the Java:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              xmlns:seekarc="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/seekArcContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <com.triggertrap.seekarc.SeekArc
            android:id="@+id/seekArc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="30dp"
            seekarc:rotation="180"
            seekarc:startAngle="30"
            seekarc:sweepAngle="300"
            seekarc:touchInside="true"
            seekarc:arcColor="#ff2ca3cc"
            seekarc:progressColor="#ffcc2d2a"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/seekArcProgress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="40sp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/controls"
        layout="@layout/controls" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am unsure how to interpret the error because my xml file wouldn't need to add what was asked right?

Comment: in your case just extend Activity instead of ListActivity and it should work

Comment: Is there a way to fix it while keeping the ListActivity?

Answer (score 1):

Your `activity_main.xml` must have a ListView with id `@android:id/list`

Quoting docs

> ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single,
>   full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire,
>   you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout
>   with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST
>   contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if 
>   it's in code)

But in your code where are you having `setListAdapter`?. You can as well extend `Activity` instead of `ListAcitvity`

Comment: Okay. it needs to extend Activity instead of ListActivity? and I need to completely changed the linearlayout to a list instead? I am still trying to understand why

Comment: @XiJiaopin nothing more to change extend Activity that's all. In case you want a list then its a different situation. but looking at the code i don't see that

Comment: @XiJiaopin why do you need `ListActivity` in the first place?

Comment: @Kushan i guess you meant to comment on someother post

Comment: @Raghunandan yea, thanks :) i was wondering why i did not get a response from the post where i intended the comment to be. This solves that mystery lol