# How do I find/create missing ListView with id - R.id.list? [android]

Tags: android, android-resources

My android app does not work, I traced the bug and found it is this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.example.twittersearches_erjan/com.example.twittersearches_erjan.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

How do I find R.id.list and remove this bug?

Comment: your xml layout should have listview widget who's name is `'android.R.id.list'`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050817/your-content-must-have-a-listview-whose-id-attribute-is-android-r-id-list)

Comment: Specify id of your list view: android:id="@+id/list"

Comment: Remove `import android.R;` from imports packages

Comment: possible duplicate of [RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040374/runtimeexception-your-content-must-have-a-listview-whose-id-attribute-is-andro)

Answer (score 2):

in your xml layout :

```
<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list" //<-- replace your id tag with this
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're extending `ListActivity`, try to use the follow `ListView` in your xml.

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Or, you can just extend norml `Activity` and use your own `ListView` with your own `id`.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your listview in the layout xml to use your own layout id

```
android:id="@+id/list"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```